# Wildly Swarm: Setup a project with separeted modules using maven

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to setup a wildfly swarm project with maven. My structure should look like this:

- project-build (wildfly swarm should generate here the -swarm.jar file including project-rest and project-ejb)
- project-rest (own pom.xml)
- project-ejb (own pom.xml)

I can build the project successfully and deploy the project but I have no access to the rest-interface.

Any idea how to resolve my issue?

Comment: Do you have the ApplicationConfig configured? Here an example http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-example-with-application/README.html

Comment: @Sergio Wildfly-Swarm doesn't require the ApplicationConfig. The applicationPath ist set to "/" if no ApplicationConfig ist configured. When I paste my source code to the project-build module it works properly.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue using the following project example with wildfly swarm:

https://github.com/hwellmann/wildfly-swarm-example-multi-module

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.